# Values in loop in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops

When I use this loop:

```
while Start_time_hours == Start_time_hours and Start_time_minutes == Start_time_minutes:
    Start_time_minutes += 5
    Start_time_hours += (Start_time_minutes / 60)
    Start_time_minutes %= 60
    if Start_time_hours == 23 and Start_time_minutes == 55:

            Start_time_hours = 0
            Start_time_minutes = 0
```

I have a lack of 2355, how to write it to not miss that value?
Executing my loop gives me this:

```
23 35
23 40
23 45
23 50
00 00
00 05
00 10
00 15
00 20
00 25
00 30
```

As you can see 2355 is missing, how to avoid that, but all those variables are `input`'s, I didn't want to litter :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
 Start_time_hours += (Start_time_minutes / 60)
    Start_time_minutes %= 60
    str(Start_time_minutes)
    str(Start_time_hours)
    str(End_time_minutes)
    str(End_time_hours)
    Start_time_hours_format = '{:02}'.format(Start_time_hours)
    Start_time_minutes_format = '{:02}'.format(Start_time_minutes)
    End_time_hours_format = '{:02}'.format(End_time_hours)
    End_time_minutes_format = '{:02}'.format(End_time_minutes)
    int(Start_time_minutes)
    Start_time_minutes += 5
```

This code gave me an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your real code has a `print` at the top of the loop, before you update the values for the next run. Problem is, you're making the changes to your values to skip 5 minutes before you handle the edge case, and the edge case is equivalent to skipping 5 minutes as well, thus the skipped value.

You could fix this by simply making an `if`/`else` so the edge case is exclusive from the normal case, e.g.:

```
while ...:
    print Start_time_hours, Start_time_minutes
    if Start_time_hours == 23 and Start_time_minutes == 55:
        Start_time_hours = 0
        Start_time_minutes = 0
    else:
        Start_time_minutes += 5
        Start_time_hours += (Start_time_minutes / 60)
        Start_time_minutes %= 60
```

which prevents both adjustments from being performed. That said, you don't really need to special case this. You can just handle rollover on the hours the same way you do with minutes. Your loop condition is also nonsensical (you're checking if two values are equal to themselves), so just make it an infinite loop (obviously, if you have a real end condition, use that, or the program will never stop until killed):

```
while 1:
    print Start_time_hours, Start_time_minutes

    Start_time_minutes += 5
    # For Python 2/3 portability, explicitly use floor division operator, //
    Start_time_hours += Start_time_minutes // 60
    Start_time_minutes %= 60
    # Same as minutes, just roll back to 0 by reducing to remainder mod 24
    Start_time_hours %= 24
```

By and large, the goal with most edge cases is to avoid handling them with special code; if you can unconditionally perform a cheap action that fixes the edge case, but is harmless to the common case, that's the best of all possible worlds. The code is always invoked, so it's far less likely to contain bugs (since most bugs would break the common case too).

Comment: Allow me to clarify, I didn't put most of my code, because as I have noticed on this very webside I continously get hated by my questions.


About the question:
My real code asks for `input` for start and end - hour and minute, where each step takes 5 minutes. If I use `if/else` then I will print only one of the values so 2355, but the loop will stop. I use this code for my plots, so I don't use `print`, and I use `Start_time_hours == Star_time_hours` to 'tell' python I want to start here. Thanks for a wide response btw. :)

Comment: @Hiddenguy: `Start_time_hours == Start_time_hours` is (barring some weirdness with stuff like floating point NaN values) definitionally true. The only thing you're "telling" Python with it is to perform a pointless test before continuing, rather than just continuing unconditionally. Whatever else you think you're "telling" Python is entirely in your head.

Comment: Also, side-note: Minimizing your code is good, but you still need a reproducible problem for others to evaluate, see [MCVE]. I made a guess at a `print` function, and even using plotting software in your real code, reducing it to a `print` in your [MCVE] is perfectly reasonable assuming it still exhibits the same problem (and preferred, since `print` is simpler than the plotting software boilerplate).